# What is the Windows command-line analogue of the Mac command 'open'?

Tags: windows, macos, shell, command-line, command-line-interface

Mac OS X has a neat little command-line function 'open'.

```
% open <file>
```

Does whatever a double-click on that file would do. But via the command-line (Terminal).

Does Windows have something like this? How do I get a non-executable file to be opened with the default program in the OS for that file-type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is `start "<file>"`.

Comment: Note also that if your file contains spaces you need `start "" "filename"`.

Comment: Does not work in all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a recognised file type, you can simply type the filename, and it will open it in your preferred application. For example,

```
my_favorite_porn.mp4
```

is not something you should do when your wife is nearby :-)

Note that, if it's a Windows application, it will auto-magically satrt in the background and your prompt will be returned to you. If it's something like a command-line application, it will run in the context of the current command window. If you want to start those in a *separate* window, you can use:

```
start cmdlineprog.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

­­­­­­­­

```
explorer <file>
```

Comment: Please don't add meaningless content just to increase the character count. You should want your content here to be as high quality as possible.

Comment: @0x7fffffff, I have explained my motivation, but that comment has been censored.